# Формы в битрикс

Tags: битрикс, формы

У меня стоит задача к элементам на странице прикрепить Яндекс.Метрику. Простые кнопки(статичные) я нашёл где находятся, но вот где находятся формы? Создатели шаблона aspro. Может кто знает, где могут находится всплывающие form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Шаблоны АСПРО для форм используют инфоблоки. Вам нужно искать вызов шаблона компонента `iblock.element.add` или `iblock.element.edit`. И нужный шаблон уже если надо дорабатывать.

Comment: Спасибо! Уже почти разобрался